# Outlook Express 6 - Spam Blocker for a Novice?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention, outlook-express

One of my associates is a novice with computers. They get 50+ spams per day mixed in with their legitimate email. I've been using gmail for 6 years now, so I'm a bit out of the loop on spam blocking.

What is a good spam blocking mechanism for a novice to use with Outlook Express 6 that has whitelist functionality?  (Don't want to lose valid emails)

Thanks

Comment: It's called [Thunderbird](http://getthunderbird.com/).

Comment: As suggested in the question, the constraint is that Outlook Express continue to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't downvote me because this is crazy, but here's what I've done.

You forward your email from your regular address (most email providers let you do this) to a gmail address.  Then use outlook to download emails from the gmail account (which removes spam).  Then configure the reply-to header in outlook to be your original email address.

This is an immediate solution and will also instantly give you web access to your email (by logging into gmail in your browser).

Comment: It's a kludge, but in the best sense. +1 for creativity and thriftiness.